# why const can't be static in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I wonder why `const` field in class can't be static?

I would like to declare such a field like that:

```
static const float pi=3.14;
```

but there appears an error `"the constant pi can't be marked static"`

Comment: What benefit would you gain from the static keyword? If you make the const public, it can be accessed from any class as if it were static.

Comment: Concept of `const` is already static, as you always access with `ClassName.constant`